# BibLaTeX/Biber: Truncate author list, but not book editor list

Tags: biblatex, biber

I've set the `maxnames` option of BibLaTeX to `1` as I only want to display the first author followed by *et al.*. For books, however, I'd like to define a dedicated `maxnames`. For example, currently, my citation of the IUPAC Gold Book looks like this:

> IUPAC: “Compendium of Chemical Terminology (the “Gold Book”)”. A. D. McNaught
> *et al.*, editors. Blackwell Scientific Publications, Oxford, 2nd edition, 1997. DOI:
> 10.1351/goldbook.

I'd like to also show the second (and last) editor A. Wilkinson, instead of truncating the list.
Up to now, I was not able to find the exact code that uses the `maxnames` option. As I don't see it in neither the `author` nor the `editor` macro, I suppose that it is used in the `\printnames` function but I don't understand the code of that function.

Is there any possibility to separate the number of authors from the number of editors?

---

#### Edit: Added an MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[%
    backend = biber,%
    style = trad-abbrv,%
    citestyle = numeric-comp,%
    sorting = nty,%
    minnames = 1,%
    maxnames = 1%
]{biblatex}

\bibliography{references}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
    @book{IUPAC1997,
        address = {Oxford},
        author = {IUPAC},
        doi = {10.1351/goldbook},
        edition = {2},
        editor = {McNaught, A. D. and Wilkinson, A.},
        isbn = {0-9678550-9-8},
        publisher = {Blackwell Scientific Publications},
        title = {{Compendium of Chemical Terminology (the “Gold Book”)}},
        year = {1997}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

This should be cited.\cite{IUPAC1997}

\printbibliography[heading = bibnumbered]

\end{document}
```

In my local document, I've used the `trad-abbrv` bibstyle and modified parts of it (quotes instead of italic text etc.) but nothing that is of relevance for this issue, thus I prefer sharing the shorter MWE with the `trad-abbrv` style.

Comment: The output you show does not look like the output one would get from the standard `biblatex` styles. Since the best answer here depends on the style you use, we can only help you properly if you tell us more about your bib setup. This is best done in the form of a short example document that shows how you cite entries and create your bibliography (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/). An MWE also makes sure that we are all talking about the same thing and saves those trying to help you from having to recreate `.bib` entries you have already.

Comment: @moewe You're right! I just added an MWE. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`biblatex`'s `maxnames` and `minnames` options apply to all names alike. If you want finer control over different names in different types, you need to modify the relevant bibmacros. There are several different ways to get to the desired result in this case, but they would have different semantics.

In the following we stick to `maxnames=1,` and only redefine one bibmacro to print more `editor`s after the title.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    backend = biber,
    style = trad-abbrv,
    citestyle = numeric-comp,
    sorting = nty,
    minnames = 1,
    maxnames = 1,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[byeditor][-\value{listtotal}]{editor}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{editorlstr}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{IUPAC1997,
  address   = {Oxford},
  author    = {IUPAC},
  doi       = {10.1351/goldbook},
  edition   = {2},
  editor    = {McNaught, A. D. and Wilkinson, A.},
  isbn      = {0-9678550-9-8},
  publisher = {Blackwell Scientific Publications},
  title     = {Compendium of Chemical Terminology (the “Gold Book”)},
  year      = {1997},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
This should be cited. \cite{IUPAC1997}

\printbibliography[heading = bibnumbered]
\end{document}
```

[image: IUPAC. Compendium of Chemical Terminology (the “Gold Book”). A. D. McNaught and A. Wilkinson, editors. Blackwell Scientific Publications, Oxford, 2nd edition, 1997. isbn: 0-9678550-9-8. doi: 10.1351/goldbook.]

Comment: So, what does `-\value{listtotal}` actually do?

Comment: @Sam It overrides any `maxnames` settings to request all available names. The idiom is explained in the `biblatex` manual in the documentation of `\printnames` (p. 184 in v3.15).